# why is this not removing?

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I have a method to remove an object of type Ping from an array list using the iterator, but it doesn't seem to remove the object.

```
public void remover(String a){
    Iterator<Ping> it = listOfSharkNames.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
      Ping user = it.next();
      System.out.println(user.getName());

      if (user.getName().equals("Daymond")) {

      }else{
         it.remove();
      }
    }
}
```

and the result

```
Finley
Bill Nye
Buddy 
Buddy 
Mary Lee
Daymond
```

I understand this may be simple, but for the life of me I cannot see whats wrong

Comment: have you tried a debugger to check what happens when you enter the `else` block?

Comment: You are printing the elements in the loop where you are doing the removal. Have you tried to print the list again afterwards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You print out the name before deciding whether to remove it or not. Print out the contents of the `List` after the matching entries have been removed.

Comment: Exactly what I thought is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Print your list after removing the element. Currently your are printing before removing the elements.